# How to know using component from used component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have created an `EnumField` that renders a radio group and can be used in many form components.

This is the `EnumField`:

```
const EnumField = ({enum, column, caption}) => {
    if (enum === '') {
        throw new Error('You should provide the entity value');
    }
    // the rest of the code
}
```

However, now that I have many forms, I'm unable to find out **which** form is the source of the bug. I need to scan all forms to find the bug.

This is tedious and unpractical for apps with many forms.

I want to be able to know the **using component** from the **used component**.

This way I can provide more accurate error messages, to reduce troubleshooting and debugging time. For example:

```
throw new Error(`You should provide entity. Please check ${usingComponentName}`);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can specify `displayName` in parent component and pass it as a prop to `EnumField`, but you can also use React Devtools (for Chome for example), and explore *components* tree in order to find problem component.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new `props` to  `EnumField` where you can name the place it's coming from.

sothing like:

`<EnumField enum={enum} column={column} caption={caption} fromComponent='homepage'/>`

Comment: It's possible. But it's not elegant. It should be like `stack trace`.

Comment: Something like `reflection`. Something that is related to load metadata from the current execution context in React. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: what about `useRef` ?

Comment: Also if we forget to pass `fromComponent` then it won't work. We need to make it work 100%.

Comment: well..you can add `PropTypes` to your component, so it will remind you.

Comment: or you can add a check where alerts somehow when that `props` is missing

Comment: Can you elaborate on `useRef` or `check`? How can I use them to extract metadata?